# How to boundary check in gcc / mingw?

Tags: c, memory-management, mingw, boundary

Having tried this

> int main(void) {
>
> int a[10]; 
>    a[20]=5;
>
> }

gcc -Wall -O2 main.c

It gives me no warning...

It's gcc within windows (mingw) and I am not able to detect this kind of boundary limit bug

how to tell compiler to check it? can mingw do it?

thanks

Comment: If you can't upgrade your compiler, upgrade your programmers.

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382993/why-do-compilers-not-warn-about-out-of-bounds-static-array-indices

Answer (score 2):

There are attempts to deal with array bounds checking.  By default, the santdard C99 says nothing about enforcing array bounds, I believe largely because it has more overhead.

That being said you can look at sites like this where people have tried to deal with it:

http://williambader.com/bounds/example.html

Comment: Good this project http://sourceforge.net/projects/boundschecking/ have "patches" for gcc, to add -fbounds-checking flag, I think they are only for linux, but it's a start..

Answer (score 1):

There are other non-compiler tools that can use static analysis to find errors like array boundary violations. A previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632057/c-c-free-alternative-to-lint) discusses some of them. Mind you, if you're needing to run in a mingw environment that may limit your choices.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old but I think another answer I got here. Even though if you plan to do a full build on gcc, you can give a try to clang compiler (e.g. for nightly builds in large projects). It worked quite well.

An example is the output when I tried accessing index 4 where the array size is declared as 4:

```
    ex9.c:17:2: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains
          4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            numbers[4] = 4;
            ^       ~
    ex9.c:4:2: note: array 'numbers' declared here
            int numbers[4] = {0};
            ^
```

Thanks
Kajal