# Why is that crashing ? (buffer overflow)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

int main()
{
 int n,c,d,a[N],b[N];

printf("Insert elements numbers in the array\n");
 scanf("%d ", n);

printf("Insert the elements in the array\n");

for (c = 0; c < n ; c++)
scanf("%d", a[c]);

for (c=n-1,d = 0;d < n; c--,d++)
b[d]= a[c];

for(c = 0; c <n; c++)
a[c] = b[n];

printf("The array inverted is\n");

for(c=0; c<n;c++)
printf("%d\n",a[c]);

return 0;
}
```

why is that crashing ? i've tried even if with values ( N < 100 ) but that still crashes , i don't know how to fix it ? can someone help me please ? thanks !

Comment: `scanf("%d ", n);` must be `scanf("%d", &n);`

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
scanf("%d ", n);
```

invokes undefined behavior. `scanf()` needs a pointer to where the number should be stored, it should be:

```
scanf("%d ", &n);
```

The same goes for the rest of your `scanf()` calls. Also, you should check the return value to know that it succeeded in reading the data in, before relying on the variables containing valid values.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` needs the address to write to, not the actual value.

Do this instead:

```
scanf("%d", &a[c]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What they said about `scanf` needing an address.  But also, what is this doing?

```
for(c = 0; c <n; c++)
  a[c] = b[n];
```

`n` is the number of elements in each array, so calling `b[n]` will give you a (possibly unannounced) problem.  The compiler tends to not warn about that kind of out-of-bounds access (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382993/why-do-compilers-not-warn-about-out-of-bounds-static-array-indices)).

I suspect you intended to copy `b` into `a` anyway, and not copy one value to every element of `a`, but that's purely speculation since you haven't declared what the expected input or output is.

Answer (score 0):

> why is that crashing ?

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_%28computing%29) says:

> A crash (or system crash) in computing is when a computer or a program (such as a software application or an operating system) stops functioning properly. Oftentimes, it will then exit after encountering these errors. The program responsible may appear to freeze until a crash reporting service documents the details of the crash. If the program is a critical part of the operating system kernel, the entire computer may crash, often resulting in a fatal system error. This behavior is called "crashing".
>
> Typical errors that result in application crashes include:
>
> - attempting to read or write memory that is not allocated for reading or writing by that application (segmentation fault) or x86 specific (general protection fault)
> - attempting to execute privileged or invalid instructions
> - attempting to perform I/O operations on hardware devices to which it does not have permission to access
> - passing invalid arguments to system calls
> - attempting to access other system resources to which the application does not have permission to access (bus error)
> - attempting to execute machine instructions with bad arguments (depending on CPU architecture): divide by zero, operations on denorms or NaN values, memory access to unaligned addresses, etc.

In your program, the statements

```
scanf("%d ", n);
```

and

```
scanf("%d", a[c]);
```

causing your program to crash.

As others suggested place `&` operator before the `scanf` arguments

```
scanf("%d ", &n); 
scanf("%d", &a[c]);
```