# C Exam Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am doing previous year C programming exam. And I came up with this:

A program (see below) defines the two variables x and y.

It produces the given output.  Explain why the character ‘A’ appears in the output of variable x.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    char x[6] = "12345\0";
    char y[6] = "67890\0";
    y[7]='A';
    printf("X: %s\n",x);
    printf("Y: %s\n",y);
}
```

Program output:
X: 1A345
Y: 67890

---

It has pretty high points (7). And I don't know how to explain it in detail. My answer would be:

char array (y) only have 6 chars allocated so changing 7th character will change whatever is after that in stack.

Any help would highly appreciated! (I'm only 1st year)

Comment: The `\0` counts as one character. It looks like for some reason the early termination causes the 7 to loop around and change the 2nd character to A.

Comment: Your answer is generally correct. But more generally - it is undefined behaviour, so making assumptions here would be wrong.

Comment: `y[7]` is the eight element of that array (well, would be if that array had that many).

Comment: Show [this](https://ideone.com/4hoIv1) to your instructor.

Comment: Exploit exam question rather than introduction to programming.

Comment: @EugeneSh. (exactly. and these kind of teachers should probably be fired right away.)

Comment: @Mercurial yeah you are probably right. Otherwise this would just be ...?

Comment: I don't know much about the stack's layout in memory, but if the output is due to the `y[7] = A` that implies that the variables are _reverse_ ordered. `x` was declared before `y` - doesn't it? This seems strange to me.

Comment: Thank you everyone. On the next year's exam there is this additional question added: What 
would happen if we change the line y[7]='1'; to x[7]='1'

I think I would say that I don't know what would happen it might not work?
What should I say in this situation?

Comment: @TamásSzabó it's fairly common that the stack grows downwards, so if the order of variables is preserved, and they are pushed onto the stack, then the second variable will reside at a lower address.

Comment: Could you share/link the rest of the exam?

Comment: @user1717828 www.paulikas.eu/SCC150.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Your formal answer should be that this program yields **undefined behavior**.

The C-language standard does not define the result of an out-of-bound access operation.

With `char y[6]`, by reading from or writing into `y[7]`, this is exactly what you are doing.

Some compilers may choose to allocate array `x[6]` immediate after array `y[6]` in the stack.

So by writing `'A'` into `y[7]`, this program might indeed write `'A'` into `x[1]`.

But the standard does not dictate that, so it depends on compiler implementation.

---

As others have implied on previous comments to your question, if it was really given on a formal exam, then you may want to consider continuing your studies elsewhere...

Comment: With all due respects, I disagree with the comment that "go study elsewhere if this appear on an exam". My teacher was a decent guy, and my class got a very similar question during my Intro to C course. As he returned our exams, he declared the entire class was wrong and that he would not count this question in the total. There were a few more questions like that in subsequent exams. That was how he made us remember some of the more egregious quirks of C till this day.

Comment: @ZoffDino: First of all, I apologize if this statement seemed or sounded patronizing. This was not the intention. But with all due respect, if your teacher gave you a similar question on your exam and then ruled it out under the claim that the entire class was wrong, then either he was not decent enough to admit that he was wrong in giving such question, or he wasn't **knowledgeable** enough to understand that the question itself was wrong in nature. "Explain why the character `‘A’` appears in the output of variable `x`" - there is simply no guarantee that `‘A’` will appear in `x`!

Comment: again, I think you understood my comment. We used a standardized C compiler for the course and that compiler would have returned the same result as this question. He then explained that it was really undefined. We should have marked "undefined" even though it was a multiple choice. On subsequent tests he intentionally inserted more tricky questions like that. Anyone who could correctly point out what the standard (C89) said would get extra marks. He drilled many of those quirks into my head.

Comment: Many of us thought he was a jerk at the time, but years later, I started to understand why he did that. He highlighted these problems by proving that they are so far against our expectations. There's more to teaching than just giving grades.

Comment: @ZoffDino: I admit that I have never heard the term "standardized C compiler". There might be such thing, there might not. But in any case, such compiler would not change the standard of the C-language itself. And that standard does not define the allocation of local variables - not their order in the stack, and not the fact that they should be allocated on the stack to begin with. In fact, I'm not sure if the standard even defines what a stack is. Writing code that works on one compiler but not necessarily on others is a major flaw, which could lead you to deal with extremely difficult bugs!

Comment: And bottom line, your teacher may have given you a similar question, expecting you to answer with "undefined behavior", but the question at hand explicitly states that the character `'A'` appears in the array `x`, and that is simply not necessarily true.

Answer (score 2):

The classic stack corruption problem in C. With the help of a debugger, you will find that your frame stack will look like this after the original assignments:

```
67890\012345\0
```

`y` points to the char `6`. `y[7]` means 7 positions after that (`2`). So `y[7] = 'A'` replaces the char 2.

Access array beyond bound is undefined in the C standard, just one more quirk of C to be aware of. Some references:

- [Understanding stack corruption](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/understanding-stack-corruption-c-t27207/)
- [Why do compilers not warn about out-of-bounds static array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382993/why-do-compilers-not-warn-about-out-of-bounds-static-array-indices)

Comment: But `x` is declared before `y`. Shouldn't they be in the same order in memory?

Comment: You understand what a *stack* is right? Last in first out. That's why `y` is before `x`.

Comment: Zoff Dino, thanks. What would happen if we would change x[7] = 1. That would go out of stack and would change program's code?

Comment: @PiDev it's likely to have no effect on this tiny example. But for more complex programs it may give you a seg fault. To really understand it, you need to know the memory layout of C: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Comment: @Tamás Szabó  `C` does not require the contents of `x` to be addressed before `y` even if `x` declared before `y`.  A compiler may do so one day and compile differently the next day.  To make `x y` have a certain order, put them in a structure.