# Why doesn't the compiler warns me about an obvious error?

Tags: c

So, I just studied the **Arrays** material and got a problem... 
I got this following code:

```
int a[5]; 
int i;
for(i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

I declared on an array that its length is 5.
[image] 
Then, I ran a `for` loop from 0 to 10 that inserts numbers into `a[i]`.
I used this table (which I created) to understand what happened during the execute time: 
[image] 
You see the red arrow? That's where the loop she be stopped, because they `a[]` cannot get more than 5 values into it. Which mean, that `a[6]` doesn't exist. 
 Even though, it keeps asking for numbers, and keeps saving them into the array. 
One more thing, I'm currently using **Dev C++** compiler.
Does anyone has an idea why is it happening? 
Thanks!

Comment: C is designed by programmers for programmers. If you tell the compiler that you want to shoot yourself in the foot, it won't stop you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do compilers not warn about out-of-bounds static array indices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382993/why-do-compilers-not-warn-about-out-of-bounds-static-array-indices)

Comment: Compilers just check the syntactic correctness of the program.  They don't actually execute your logic to see if the program can possibly fail at runtime.

Comment: To add to what @ThomasPadron-McCarthy noted, C is like that friend whom you can always rely upon to be up for a night on the town.  Dependable in all the ways that count, but never one to stop you from doing something that you might regret later.

Comment: This question should not close, because the comments here are the best way to make someone understand why `C` allows *Undefined Behavior*. :)

Answer (score 6):

C doesn't have any standard on constraint on array index out of bound checking.

That means programs are free to violate the index rule. It is upto the programmers to check the array index constraint.

And, that will result in an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This error has nothing to do with the compiler. Whether it's C or Java, as long as it does not violate the language syntax and semantic, the code will compile.

What you have is a logical error which could be detected by the language run-time environment, e.g. JVM, which what C lacks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is called *Undefined Behavior*. It will not show an error when you go beyond the index of an array.

This means that the behavior that your code will show, cannot be defined.

---

On a side note, I would like to add something I read somewhere. **Please note that this is just something I read, it may be wrong, but it does make sense.** In `C`, some behaviors are not made into errors, because `C` believes in that the programmers are smart enough not to make mistakes like this.

Comment: But if it is cannot be defined, why when I print `a[6]` it prints it perfectly?

Comment: @rolory: "undefined behavior" simply means that the compiler isn't required to handle the situation in a particular way; your code didn't clobber anything important, so it *appeared* to run without any errors.

Comment: @rolory: Put another way, if `a[5]` is memory location `0x600`, then `a[6]` is memory location `0x604`.  It's invalid from the programmer's point of view, but given that the compiler makes no guarantees, the computer sees it as a perfectly valid location in memory.  Coincidentally, this partly explains how a buffer overflow attack works - what's to stop me from reading/modifying `a[6]`?

Answer (score 1):

C does not perform array bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

C does not do any bounds checking on array accesses (that is, the compiler will not inject any code that will throw an exception if you try to access an element outside of the array bounds).  The language standard does not define what should happen if you access items outside of the array bounds; you basically void the warranty on your code when you do that.

The result can include anything from running to completion with no apparent errors, to throwing a segfault, to triggering a malware routine, etc.  Again, the language definition does not mandate any particular behavior for such an error.

Remember that C is a product of the early '70s; bounds checks slow you down, and the C philosophy is that the programmer is in the best position to know whether a bounds check is really necessary or not.  The compiler assumes you know how big your array is, and that you know not to try to read or write past the end of it.